# react-native-track-player not playing song requested from Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, express, react-native-track-player

I made an expressjs server which has a 'songs' route, that provides .mp3 files.
Songs Route code:

```js
import express from "express"
const path = require("path")

const router = express.Router()

...

router.get("/download/:filename", (req, res, next) => {
  // 'test.mp3' is located in the same folder as this file
  const file = path.join(__dirname, `${req.params.filename}`)
  res.download(file)
})

module.exports = router
```

I followed the "Getting Started" Session from 'react-native-track-player' and copied the code for testing, but requesting 'test.mp3' from my server.
MusicPlayer code:

```js
export default function PlayerComponent() {
  const playbackState = usePlaybackState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setup();
  }, []);

  async function setup() {
    await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer({});
    await TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
      stopWithApp: false,
      capabilities: [
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PLAY,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PAUSE,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_SKIP_TO_NEXT,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_STOP,
      ],
      compactCapabilities: [
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PLAY,
        TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PAUSE,
      ],
    });
  }

  async function togglePlayback() {
    const currentTrack = await TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack();

    // Creating a test track
    const track = {
      id: '111',
      url: 'http://X.X.X.X:5000/api/songs/download/test.mp3', // My Express server URL
      title: 'Test',
      artist: 'myself',
      genre: 'Pop Music',
      date: '2014-05-20T07:00:00+00:00', 
      artwork:
        'https://images.genius.com/23eaf0161396f67cc3bf264ca148a2b7.668x668x1.jpg',
    };
    if (currentTrack === null) {
      await TrackPlayer.add(track);
      await TrackPlayer.play();
    } else {
      if (playbackState === TrackPlayer.STATE_PAUSED) {
        await TrackPlayer.play();
      } else {
        await TrackPlayer.pause();
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <LinearGradient
        colors={['#120D14', '#C00EFF']}
        start={{x: 0.5, y: 0.7}}
        end={{x: 0.5, y: 0}}
        style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.topArea}>
            <MaterialIcons name="keyboard-arrow-down" size={35} color="white" />
          </View>
          <Player
            onNext={skipToNext}
            onPrevious={skipToPrevious}
            onTogglePlayback={togglePlayback}
          />
        </View>
      </LinearGradient>
    </View>
  );
}
```

But after clicking the play button (that is inside the Player Component), the music doesn't play. However, when I use the track provided by the documentation, it works just fine. (Code Bellow):

```js
const track = {
      id: '1111',
      url:
        'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1AjPwylDJgR8DOnmJWeRgZzjsohi-7ekj',
      title: 'Longing',
      artist: 'David Chavez',
      artwork: 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/100/200/200.jpg'
    };
```

This got me thinking that the problem was with my expressjs server.
So I started making some tests and didn't find anything too unexpected. The only thing I've realized was that when making a request to download the file with PostMan, two files are downloaded in a .mpga extension, whereas with a browser the wanted file (test.mp3) comes in .mp3 format (which is expected to happen). I'm not sure if that means something, but that's what I've figured out.

**Things that I've done**

- I've already checked and confirmed if the Request was being made by the Client.
- I've tried using 'sendFile()' instead of 'download()', but without success.

Any help is appreciated and I hope I made myself clear.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use res.sendFile method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like this:

```
app.get(
  "/music/:fileName",
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
      const { fileName } = req.params;
      const filePath = `music/${fileName}`;
      const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
      const stat = fs.statSync(filePath);

      res.set("content-type", "audio/mpeg");
      res.set("Content-Range", `bytes ${0}-${stat.size - 1}/${stat.size}`);
      res.set("accept-ranges", "bytes");
      res.set("Content-Length", `${stat.size}`);

      stream.pipe(res);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  },
);
```